# CoreLocation heading Android

Tags: android, ios, orientation, core-location, android-orientation

I am currently working on an algorithm which requires an accurate estimate of the heading of the mobile device. For the development in iOS, I do not have to estimate the user heading as the framework already provides the value of `trueHeading` via CoreLocation framework. So I do not have to implement my own fusion algorithm. The beauty of this `trueHeading` is that it is very accurate and very stable, specially when the device is resting. This enables me to troubleshoot my algorithm.

Now, I am trying to implement my algorithm in Android and I have met a roadblock that Android does not provide anything like `trueHeading`, or at least I am not aware of it. In this case, I need to use `TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR` which is very unstable, due to use of Magnetometers.

Does anyone know if Android provides something like `trueHeading` or has anybody used a better algorithm for accurate heading estimation in Android?

I have tried to install several compass apps in Android to see their performance but none reported accurate readings.

PS: I have tried my level best to explain my problem. Your help is really appreciated.

Comment: `Location` class do have  a method to get bearing(true heading).

Comment: Ok, so I tested this method `getBearing()` but it does not work indoor as GPS data is not available.

Comment: "[Android] is very unstable, due to use of Magnetometers" - I wonder how Apple determines "true heading" if not via the earth's magnetic field...