# are the reference frame for Android and iOS different?

Tags: android, ios, orientation, android-sensors, sensor-fusion

I am currently trying to get an accurate estimate of `trueHeading` for Android as asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693424/corelocation-heading-android). Disappointed that I could not find a good solution, I tried to implement my own algorithm for trueHeading estimation for Android. And in my investigation, I decided to start from scratch.

So I recorded `RAW` data from both Android and iOS when the phones (Apple iPhone 6 and Samsung Galaxy Note 3), were resting on table, screen facing upward. The `mean` values of the sensors (Accelerometer, Gyroscope and Magnetometers) are shown below:

**iPhone 6**

Accelerometer (x, y, z) = [0.0037 0.0018 -1.007]

Gyroscope     (x, y, z) = [-0.0129 -0.0062 0.0047]

Magnetometer  (x, y, z) = [134.94 122.94 -614.94]

**Samsung**

Accelerometer (x, y, z) = [0.0491 0.2289 9.3865]

Gyroscope     (x, y, z) = [-0.0060 -0.0360 -0.0281]

Magnetometer  (x, y, z) = [8.8665 21.0000 -48.2367]

I can see that iOS provides acceleration in Gs and Android provides it in m/s^2 but **why the sign of the Z component is opposite for exactly the same position?**

I am under the assumption that for both [Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html) and [iOS](http://blog.denivip.ru/index.php/2013/07/the-art-of-core-motion-in-ios/?lang=en), the axis are similar as shown in the links.

**Can someone please explain to me what am I missing and if there is anyway to get the solution for trueHeading in Android?**

Comment: Technically, [Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html#values) seems to be correct when you refer to *acceleration*: *Not* moving down along the gravitational field is equal to an absolute acceleration of 1G *upwards* (positive Z axis). The iPhone seems to provide the amount of *inertial force* caused by an acceleration.

Comment: Common 'work-around' is to have the user initially calibrate the device/app. For instance, have him hold the device with the display facing up and record the signs of the acceleration values in this position.

Comment: Btw, what is "true heading" relative to for you? Magnetic north pole, geographic pole, something else?

Comment: @HannoBinder Thank you for your reply. The key requirement is that we cant ask user to calibrate the phone. `trueHeading` relative to North Pole. So iOS gives both `magneticHeading` and `trueHeading` just not sure how they do it! Android on the other hand provides TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR which is very noisy due to magnetometer.

Comment: @chintans The offset from magnetic north to true north is known,https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:World_Magnetic_Declination_2015.pdf, and relatively static (it changes over decades). So if you know WHERE you are (via GPS) you can correct the static offset from magnetic to north. That's how they do it.